# Mobile web development

Tags: web-applications, jquery-mobile, web

I have been given an assingment to make a mobile version of a website we did previously. We are using jquery mobile. My one question is, the way jquery works by coding every page in  single file. Is this not inefficient as it loads the entire website from the get go?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a matter of perspective - yes, the initial launch may be marginally slower, however this then means you can transition between pages as they're already loaded in the DOM and also the data for these subsequent pages is there and waiting for the user; there's no further network interaction.

*edit*: Also, you're not **forced** to use a single page - see data-ajax="false".

Comment: I suppose if you look at it that way it is good. I would rather a longer initial load to have a smooth browsing afterward